# Does standing up after being knocked prone use half your current or maximum speed

Tags: dnd-5e, movement, prone

I'm DMing a campaign and one of my players is a monk with 40ft of movement. He got hit by a slow spell reducing his speed to 20ft and was knocked prone. To get up would he have to use his full 20ft as its half his max speed or only 10ft as that's half his current speed?

Comment: I've marked your question as a dupe because I think it has been asked before. This isn't a bad thing as this question might help others find that one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### He’d use 10 feet of movement (Half his speed)

The rules make no distinction between ‘current’ or ‘maximum’ speed. You only have one speed. Being slowed halves his speed, which means his Speed is now half than what it would usually be. As far as I’m aware there aren’t any rules that care about what your speed without modifiers is, and the rules for standing up when prone certainly make no reference to such a thing.